# JavaScript - Onclick navigation arrow function issue

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to be create a simple app with a navigation function. My issue is that when the user clicks the navigation it pops up but if the user click outside the navigation content, the content disappears and the navigation arrow  doesn't work. Given below is my code,

```js
const menuButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.clickfun');

menuButtons.forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', toggleButton, false));

function toggleButton() {
  const id = this.dataset.id;
  const panel = document.getElementById(id);
  if (panel.style.display === 'block') {
    panel.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    panel.style.display = 'block';
  }
} 


        var boxArray = ['box1','box2'];
        window.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event) {
            for(var i=0; i < boxArray.length; i++){
            
          var box = document.getElementById(boxArray[i]);
            if(event.target != box && event.target.parentNode != box) {
                box.style.display = 'none';
           }
                
                }
       });    
            
                  
var anchors = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a'));

anchors.map(anchor => {
 if(anchor.classList.contains('btn-open') || anchor.classList.contains('btn-down')) {
    anchor.addEventListener('click', () => {
      if(anchor.classList.contains('btn-open')) {
        anchor.classList.remove('btn-open');
        anchor.classList.add('btn-down');
      } 
       
        
        else {
        anchor.classList.add('btn-open');
        anchor.classList.remove('btn-down');
      } 
    });
  }
});
```

```css
  #box1 {
                 
                 
   position: absolute;
   top: 67px;
    left: 140px;
    width: 260px;
    height: 55px;
    padding: 6px;
     display: none;
    background: #E2E2E2;
  }
  
             
.btn-open:after, a {
    
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    content: "\f0de";
    color: #333;
    font-size: 18px;
   
}

.btn-down:after, a {
    
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    content: "\f0dd";
    color: #333;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div id="box1">
            
            
            <h2>Options Main Page</h2>
        </div>
        
        <h2>Page Content....</h2>
        
        
        <div id="box2">
            
            
            <h2>Pops Out two</h2>
        </div>
        <nav>
       
       <a data-id="box1"  class="clickfun btn-down  " href="javascript:void(0);"> About us </a><br>
```

I would really appreciate some help with this. Thanks.

Comment: what does "running into difficulties" mean?

Comment: did you see, when i click the content its popups thats close ,but the arrow still showing the up i want to be down when the content is close.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is this in `window.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event) {` you need to prevent displaying none if click is on clickfun.

```
!event.target.classList.contains('clickfun')
```

Please check code here

```js
const menuButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.clickfun');

menuButtons.forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', toggleButton, false));

function toggleButton() {
  const id = this.dataset.id;
  const panel = document.getElementById(id);
  if (panel.style.display === 'block') {
    panel.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    panel.style.display = 'block';
  }
  ChangeArrows();
}


var boxArray = ['box1', 'box2'];
window.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event) {
  for (var i = 0; i < boxArray.length; i++) {
  var anchor = document.querySelectorAll('.clickfun');
    var box = document.getElementById(boxArray[i]);    
    if (event.target != box && !boxArray.some(a=> a===event.target.parentNode.id) && !event.target.classList.contains('clickfun') && anchor[0].classList.contains('btn-open')) {
      box.style.display = 'none';
      ChangeArrows();
      event.preventDefault();
      return;
    }

  }
});


function ChangeArrows() {

  var anchor = document.querySelectorAll('.clickfun');
  if (anchor[0].classList.contains('btn-open')) {
    anchor[0].classList.remove('btn-open');
    anchor[0].classList.add('btn-down');
  } else {
    anchor[0].classList.add('btn-open');
    anchor[0].classList.remove('btn-down');
  }
}
```

```css
#box1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 67px;
  left: 140px;
  width: 260px;
  height: 55px;
  padding: 6px;
  display: none;
  background: #E2E2E2;
}

.btn-open:after,
a {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  content: "\f0de";
  color: #333;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.btn-down:after,
a {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  content: "\f0dd";
  color: #333;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="box1">
  <h2>Options Main Page</h2>
</div>

<h2>Page Content....</h2>


<div id="box2">


  <h2>Pops Out two</h2>
</div>
<nav>

  <a data-id="box1" class="clickfun btn-down" href="javascript:void(0);"> About us </a><br>
```

Comment: The arrow still not function like defult down arrow? did you see, when i click the content its popups thats close but the arrow still showing the up i want to be down when the content close.

Comment: Let me check it for you

Comment: Ya the content closing perfectly but the arrow still not get default position i mean down? when the content is closing it will be down arrow.


Thanks

Comment: Hey Thanks Friend. This what i have been looking for it. Thank you so much friend.

Comment: @sai glad that helps you

Comment: Boss i want learn an professional JavaScript developer. can you help me out where i can learn ?

Comment: @sai Google is your friend and stackoverflow always helps you to find out best approach. Consider accepting answer if this helps you.

Comment: Thanks I tried so many tuts, but i need more practice i think. Anyway Thanks my friend.

Comment: Just code, everything works fine but the arrow function work without any click on the menu? its work everywhere in outside?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184406/discussion-between-sai-and-just-code).

Comment: Boss once again thanks, whats the issue in the code ?

Comment: When clicking outside of the box you need to check if box is open then need to execute the code. Check my edits you will get point

Comment: Thanks Friend, you helped me so much in the trouble. and also why it does not support IE 11 ?